# How can I convert a string into a byte array in c++?

Tags: c#, c++

How can I convert this C# code to C++?

```
string map = "maps\guardian";
byte[] mapName = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(map);
```

Comment: `std::string myString("hello"); myString.c_str(); //char array`?

Comment: @AlejandroDíaz Make it an answer

Comment: Might I ask why do you need it? The `std::string` object in C++ is kinda of a byte array already. I think better answers could be given if you show a actual use case.

Comment: `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(String)` converts the characters in the String (which are in the Unicode character set) to their ASCII encoding, substituting "?" for characters that aren't in the ASCII character set. Is the last bit what you are asking how to do in C++?

Comment: i Trier to write a halo online crack and in the c# Version it would work with encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string) but in c++ if i use a string, a const char or char or whatever the game will not load the map

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::string` like this

```
std::string myString("Hello World!");
const char* myConstArray = myString.c_str();
char myNonConstArray[100];
strcpy(myNonConstArray, myString.c_str());
```

both const and non-const versions there.

Answer (score 0):

Would not this suffice?:

```
std::string map = "maps\guardian";
char* asciimap = map.c_str();
```

In C++ there is no `byte` type. You only have `char`.